# Getting values in between ordinary date and timestamp from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a standard mysql timestamp in this format 2011-11-14 20:06:24 . This timestamp will be added whenever a new record is added to the table with the name lead.

I have two input fields for the user to enter from date and to date in dd/mm/yyyy format. Once the user enters both dates and press a button the values will be passsed to other field to get the records from the table lead which are inserted between the time range.

I tried the below query but its not working

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(added_on, '%d/%m/%Y') as date
FROM    lead
WHERE   added_on BETWEEN "10/11/2011" AND "14/11/2011"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use standard format for dates, datetimes and timestamps: `'2011-11-14'` and not `'14/11/2011'`.

Use single quotes, not double quotes.

If `added_on` is a timestamp, you should not use `BETWEEN` or you'll lose almost all records from the last day because `'2011-11-14'` will be converted to `'2011-11-14 00:00:00'`. Use this instead:

```
WHERE   added_on >= '2011-11-10'
  AND   added_on <  '2011-11-15'              --- note the "< the next day"
```

or

```
WHERE   added_on >=  '2011-11-10'
  AND   added_on <  ('2011-11-14' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

---

You should read carefully the **[`MySQL docs: TIMESTAMP properties`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html)** page for how timestamps are handled (and auto-inserted, updated) in MySQL and the **[`MySQL docs: Timezone support`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for your timely response ypercube. I tried this as per your suggestion. I have one row which is inserted today(20011-11-15) but it returns no results.  select * from lead  WHERE   added_on >= '2011-11-10'  AND   added_on <  '2011-11-15'

Comment: You have to use the **next day** with **<**: `... added_on < '2011-11-16' `

Comment: = was missing i tried    select * from lead  WHERE   added_on >= '2011-10-15'  AND   added_on <=  '2011-11-16'  and its working like a charm. Thanks alot yepercube :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination yepercube..can i store the number of records added in the given month range in a separate variables by month?

Answer (score 2):

you have to convert the date first in php

you can use "date" function of php to covert the date format according to mysql, as follows:

```
$converteddate =  date('Y-m-d',strtotime($yourposteddate));
```

This will return date in format, e.g. 2011-08-15 which can be understood by mysql and then use it as normal in mysql.

Comment: yeppercube's answer was pretty helpful Arfeen. The above method is quite effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(added_on, '%m/%d/%Y') as date
FROM    lead
WHERE   added_on BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT("20/11/2011",'%m/%d/%Y')
AND     DATE_FORMAT("21/11/2011", '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: This is a wrong way to do search in the db. No index can be used.